# Using DUTIS to prove that $\int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1} \ln^{n}(x) \, dx = (-1)^{n} \frac{n!}{a^{n+1}} $

Tags: calculus, integration

For a positive number $a$, $$\int_0^1 x^{a-1}dx=  \frac{1}{a}. $$

Prove that $$\int_0^1 x^{a-1} \ln^{n}(x) \, dx= (-1)^{n} \frac{n!}{a^{n+1}}$$ for all positive integers $n$.

This question was part of a math exercise sheet about differentiation under the integral sign, but I'm totally confused with this exercise.

All I get is:  $$\frac{d}{da}\int_0^1 x^{a-1} \, dx=\int_0^1 e^{(a-1) \ln x} \ln x \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1} \ln x \, dx$$

Answer (score 3):

They want you to differentiate both sides of the equation $n$-times.

$$ \frac{d^{n}}{d a^{n}} \int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1} \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \partial^{n}}{\partial a^{n}} \, x^{a-1} \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1} \ln^{n}(x) \, dx = \frac{d^{n}}{da^{n}} \frac{1}{a}  $$

You can use induction to show that $$\frac{d^{n}}{da^{n}} \frac{1}{a} = (-1)^{n} \frac{n!}{a^{n+1}}. $$

Comment: Omg, I can't even express how stupid I feel right now. I even wrote it in the title. :D Thanks a lot...